# Yii2 MongoDB distinct count

Tags: php, mongodb, count, yii2, distinct

How to get count distinct values from the collection using query?
Now I am using this solution:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('collection_name');
$result = $collection->distinct('field_id');
return count($result);
```

Collection example:

```
    {
       {a: 2},
       {a: 2},
       {b: 3},
       {c: 4}    
    }
```

Result must be:

```
3
```

Comment: $query = new Query;
$count = $query->from('collection_name')->distinct('field_id')->count();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [aggregation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-collection.html#aggregate()-detail) framework for this:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('collection_name');
$result = $collection->aggregate(
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$field_id'
    )),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => 1,
        'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this not tested but you can get your results, make some changes if exception occur.

```
use yii\mongodb\Query;
$query = new Query;
$count = $query->from('collection_name')->distinct('field_id')->count();
```

[More detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-query.html#distinct()-detail)

Comment: Call to a member function count() on array error coming